# Investment Valuation Data Model Design Issue

Tags: data-warehouse, subtype, supertype, star-schema-datawarehouse, kimball

I was wondering if somebody could shed some light on the below.

I am currently working on building a kimball data warehouse within the financial sector specifically within the pensions industry.

Currently we are working to integrate the business process of valuations on a scheme.

The requirement is to store all valuations regardless of the product in a single FACT table for reporting. There are many different type of products which a pension can hold (Portfolio, Securities, Property etc) , so we have decided to go down the route of creating supertype and subtype dimensions. There will be one supertype for product which will contain common fields and then a subtype dimension for each product which will contain further detail.

The issue we are currently having is that a security can be held within a portfolio , but on the flip side the portfolio might not hold any investments but still contain a value (may be down to how we store the underlying data).

We do not want to create a single valuation line within the fact table for the portfolio if it has underlying investments we would just expect to show the underlying investments but somehow tie this back to the porfolio. If the porfolio has no underlying investments that we know of we would expect to store a line within the FACT table with just the value of the portfolio which would key directly to the product table.

Does anyone have any suggestions on this?

Here is a structure of how the data is held in the source system.

[image]

Here is my proposed design with all of the investment dimensions inter-changeable and the product dimension being core  , however this falls over because there is no link between the underlying investment holding and the portfolio.

[image]

Updated model with Portfolio Key within Fact

[image]

Comment: Is the obvious answer to aggregate the underlying portfolio investments within the original fact table and create a separate valuation line fact table with the underlying details

Comment: Hi - what issue are you actually asking for help with? You seem to have described a scenario and then provided a solution to it. Are you asking whether your solution will work, if there is a better solution, or what?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you post some tables with sample data (portfolio, security, etc) that you are currently using and what you are expecting out of it.

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for the reply, i have edited the original post and added what the tables look like in the source system with some sample data. As you can see a portfolio valuation can be held on its own without any underlying assets but can also be made up of underlying assets. I am hoping to build one Fact table which will hold all valuations , but i would still want to maintain the breakdown of the portfolio assets and i am not sure how this will work if i have one central product dimension. What i am asking is what would be the best solution to the problem.

Comment: The short answer is: create a "dummy" asset record in your dimension to represent a single "special" security that can be rolled up to a portfolio. In my view creating "records that aren't really there to support reporting" is a pretty standard DW data modelling approach.

Comment: How would this work in terms of providing all of the underlying detail of the security? From my understanding the security would already exist in the dimProduct table as a single line however there will be no way to link that back to the portfolio unless some kind of portfolio key was introduced to the fact but this wont be relevant to investments such as property etc.

Comment: I have added my proposed design to the original post but as mentioned this falls over as there is no link between the portfolio and investment holding and it would also mean a value would be stored at the portfolio level and the investment holding level , which would duplicate the valuation

Comment: If I've understood you correctly, a Portfolio is not a product - so you need a separate Portfolio Dim with its own key. In your Product Dim table(s) you create a dummy record to use when a portfolio doesn't have any real products

Comment: Yes i think that works , the portfolio is still valued but doesn't always contain any underlying individual investments (that we have sight of). The updated design therefore should be like the one i have updated in the original post.